# How to handle net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Axios - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, axios

I received the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when chose the Room on the dropdown list and clicked on the get room button. Below is my code

In front end

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        roomID: ''
      };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {    
    this.setState({roomID: event.target.value}); 
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log('Room chosen is: ' + this.state.roomID);
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.get(`https://localhost:8080/room_selected`)
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function(){

      });
  }
render() {
<form>
                <Card
                  plain
                  content={
                    // <div>
                      <FormGroup controlId="formControlsSelect">
      <ControlLabel>Select Room Number</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl componentClass="select" placeholder="select" value={this.state.room} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </FormControl>
      <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
      <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit} class="btn btn-secondary" justify-content="center">Get Room</Button></div>
    </FormGroup>    
                  }

                />
              </form>
}
```

In backend

```
app.get('/room_selected', function (req, res){
    var client = 'a@gmail.com';
    var room = 'Room 1';

    var query = connection.query ('SELECT ClientID FROM clientDevices WHERE DeviceName = ?', [room]);
    if (client == query[0].ClientID){
        res.send('Success');
    } else {
        res.send('The selected room does not have a device attached');      
    }
});
console.log("Listening on port 8080");
app.listen(8080);
```

Are there any ways to handle this error and also can get the user to receive data from the backend to the frontend? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In you Front end code

```
 axios.get(`https://localhost:8080/room_selected`)
```

As I see in your Backend code, it doesn't use any SSL cert, so try change to HTTP instead. Your problem can come from the problem of CORS when they do the preflight check. Change to:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/room_selected`)
```

Comment: so did you try change from https to http in the fe code? does it help ?

Comment: I got 'https://localhost:8080/room_selected' when running the function room_selected in the backend so I put the URL into axios_get to received the data from this function display in the frontend